# Can peppers be saved after the branch broke off?

Tags: bell-peppers

I had four beautiful young peppers on one branch, but it became too heavy & the branch broke off. If the peppers were still green when the branch broke will they continue to ripen

Comment: I'd imagine so.  Tomatos - which are also part of the same nightshade family - continue to ripen so it is reasonable to assume peppers will as well.

Answer (score 2):

Basing my answer on chillies, the peppers should continue to ripen.  Just leave them in a bowl on your benchtop/countertop

Answer (score 0):

What do You mean "ripen"?! Peppers are cool to eat any time(unlike tomatoes that are slightly toxic when unripe).

With that out of the way I would pick them from the branch as the leaves radiate moisture. And eat them. I routinely do that with tomatoes and peppers(certain cat...). Tomatoes turn red a couple of weeks later but peppers just dry out. Sometimes rot.